# Core Data: Trouble getting the managedObjectContext and model

Tags: ios, core-data

I am a newbie with Core Data and I'm having trouble with it... This is what I get when I access self.managedObjectContext from the app delegate:

```
#9  0x013db635 in objc_exception_throw
#10 0x00d00df3 in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator initWithManagedObjectModel:]
#11 0x00002b9d in -[appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] at appDelegate.m:158
#12 0x00002924 in -[appDelegate managedObjectContext] at appDelegate.m:121
#13 0x00002736 in -[appDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] at appDelegate.m:32
```

The debugger stops at this line of code in the persistentStoreCoordinator method:

```
persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
```

Maybe this has something to do with it: I deleted the .xcdatamodel and .xcdatamodelId file, and created a new model from scratch (with the same name, through File -> New File -> Data Model). I tried cleaning everything, resetting the iPhone simulator content, etc. But I keep getting this error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here's a *not very subtle* solution that fixed my problem:

1. Created a new project with same name in a different folder
2. Selected all the entities from the modeling window of the corrupted project and copied them on the new project data model canvas
3. Saved the new project and closed it
4. From the finder, I replaced all the old *.xcdatamodel files in my corrupted project folder with the ones of my new project

And that's it!